# Infinite Parallax Background in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, parallax, game-development

I have been trying to get infinite parallaxing working with Unity 2d. I have gotten the parallaxing to work but I start to run into issues when trying to make the background continue infinitely.

I should mention that the camera backgrounds are restricted movement on the X axis only. The Player can jump and move up and down but the background and camera Y position stays constant.

The main problem is that out of my 11 backgrounds used for the parallax effect, only the first one ever gets cloned and none of them get destroyed when off screen(Although this is more of a secondary concern at this point).

I've tried a few different ways to detect that the player is in front of the background. I've used GameObjects attached to each background object and compared them to the Player's position. That didn't work very well so in my current version, I'm using cameras to detect the Player's position.

My process for creating the infinite background is as follows:

```
Loop: Through all the background images and do the following checks:

  If: Player position is outside the bounds of the current background on the left.

    Then: Create a copy of the current background and place it to the left the current background.

If: Player position is outside the bounds of the current background on the right.

    Then: Create a copy of the current background and place it to the right the current background.
```

To clean up the backgrounds, I just check if the Player is in front of one of the backgrounds and if not then delete it.

Below is the working parallax code along with the attempted infinite background code at the bottom:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParallaxBackground : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] backgrounds;
    public float smooting = 1f;
    public int offset = -1;
    public Transform cam;
    public Camera Lcam;
    public Camera Rcam;

    //private Transform cam;
    private Vector3 previousCamPos;
    private float[] parallaxScales;
    private GameObject[] backgroundClones;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        previousCamPos = cam.position;

        parallaxScales = new float[backgrounds.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.Length; i++) {
            parallaxScales[i] = backgrounds[i].transform.position.z * offset;
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        // Handle paralaxing
        for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.Length; i++) {
            float parallax = (previousCamPos.x - cam.position.x) * parallaxScales[i];

            float backgroundTargetPosX = backgrounds[i].transform.position.x + parallax;

            Vector3 backgroundTargetPos = new Vector3(backgroundTargetPosX, backgrounds[i].transform.position.y, backgrounds[i].transform.position.z);

            backgrounds[i].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(backgrounds[i].transform.position, backgroundTargetPos, smooting * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        /* Handle continuous backgrounds*/
        for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.Length; i++)
        {

            // Left Camera
            float pointL = Lcam.WorldToViewportPoint(backgrounds[i].transform.position).x;

            // Right Camera
            float pointR = Rcam.WorldToViewportPoint(backgrounds[i].transform.position).x;


            // Check if the object is within the Left camera
            if (pointL < 1)
            {
                Destroy(backgroundClones[i]);
                var clone = Instantiate(backgrounds[i].gameObject);
                clone.transform.position = Rcam.transform.position;
                backgroundClones[i] = clone;
            }
            else if (pointR > 0)
            {
                Destroy(backgroundClones[i]);
                var clone = Instantiate(backgrounds[i].gameObject);
                clone.transform.position = Lcam.transform.position;
                backgroundClones[i] = clone;
            }
        }

        /* Handle removing backgrounds*/
        for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.Length; i++)
        {
            // Main Camera
            Vector3 point = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(backgrounds[i].transform.position);

            // Left Camera
            float pointL = Lcam.WorldToViewportPoint(backgrounds[i].transform.position).x;

            // Right Camera
            float pointR = Rcam.WorldToViewportPoint(backgrounds[i].transform.position).x;


            // Check if the object is within the main camera
            if (point.x > 0 || point.x < 1)
            {

            }
            else {
                Destroy(backgrounds[i]);
            }
        }


        previousCamPos = cam.position;
    }
}
```